# Are there any Vaishyas playing a prominent role in scripture?

Tags: vaishya

Most human characters in scripture seem to be Kshatriyas, Brahmins or Sudras.

Are there any Vaishyas who play a prominent role in scripture?

By Vaishya I mean one who would qualify as a Vaishya by birth or one who is said to exhibit Vaishya gunas, whatever they may be.

This is just an afterthought - I think the scion of a long Vaishya lineage is non-existent in scripture.

Comment: Suratha in devi mahatmaya. Not a major one though

Comment: long time no hear from @Rakesh Joshi - hope all is well.

Comment: Vaishya by birth, guna or something else? :P @SK You need to specify that in the question

Comment: @rickross - edited the Q.  thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The closest one can be found in Mahabharata, There was one Vaisya warrior who fought for Dharma and Pandavas against Kauravas, he was son of Dhritarashtra, his name was [Yuyutsu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuyutsu).

Quoting from [Sambhava Parva, SECTION CXV](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01116.htm)

> And during the time when Gandhari was in a state of advanced pregnancy, **there was a maid servant of the Vaisya class who used to attend on Dhritarashtra**. During that year, O king, **was begotten upon her by the illustrious Dhritarashtra a son endued with great intelligence who was afterwards named Yuvutsu.** And because he was begotten by a
> p. 243
>
> [paragraph continues] Kshatriya upon a Vaisya woman, he came to be called Karna.
>
> **"Thus were born unto the wise Dhritarashtra a hundred sons who were all heroes and mighty chariot-fighters, and a daughter over and above the hundred, and another son Yuyutsu of great energy and prowess begotten upon a Vaisya woman.'"**

Also from [Sambhava Parva, Section CXXIX](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01130.htm):

> "Some time after, Duryodhana again mixed in the food of Bhima a poison that was fresh, virulent, and very deadly. But **Yuyutsu (Dhritarashtra's son by a Vaisya wife)**, moved by his friendship for the Pandavas, informed them of this. Vrikodara, however, swallowed it without any hesitation, and digested it completely. And, though virulent the poison produced no effects on Bhima.

Comment: I think in such cases they dont consider mothers varna right

Comment: @RakeshJoshi I am not sure about that, but this is the closest I could find.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Bhatti](http://panchatantra.org/bhetala/birth-and-growth-of-bhatti-vikramaditya.html), the younger brother of King Vikram, was the son of Chandravarna and his Vysya wife.
2. The ascetic boy, who was killed accidentally, by Prince Dasaratha , was the son of a [Vysya](https://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/ayodhya/sarga63/ayodhya_63_frame.htm) and Sudra Mother.  Thus, the ascetic boy was a Vysya.

Comment: Bhatti may be a folklore character

Comment: whether Bhatti was a character from folklore or not, is matter of dispute.  So I quoted his name.  The ascetic boy played a vital role in Ramayana, so he is a prominent person @SK

Comment: Prominent term is crucial here. You had mentioned it without qualifying it. Do you mean by that term **prominent**,  prominence as rulers or accumulation of wealth or scholarship or something else?  If not immediately, someone else may post at a later date, with complete details @SK

Comment: prominent = figure near the top in a cast of characters of a scripture @srimannarayana k v . It is meant in a dramatic sense - characters who give shape to the narrative.